# How to make sure PostgreSQL drive is thread-safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sidekiq

I would like to use `Sidekiq` for my background job. But the requirement is gem dependencies are threadsafe.

In their wiki page, they mention:

```
   Some gems can be troublesome:

   * pg (the postgres driver, make sure PG::Connection.isthreadsafe returns true)
```

I use `pg` gem for PostgreSQL.

My question is: how do I change PG::Connection.isthreadsafe to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem calls this c library call:

`PQisthreadsafe();`

Documented here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/libpq-threading.html

The relevant documentation is this :

> libpq is reentrant and thread-safe if the configure command-line
>   option --enable-thread-safety was used when the PostgreSQL
>   distribution was built.

So you will need to recompile libpg (or get the threadsafe package if available) to make it actually threadsafe.